# SQL : Select from table based on other table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have given lot of time try to solve it out but could not reach to the solution.
Below are my tables. What i am trying to do is delete from t1  when PO ,SKU, LOC and REC matches between t1 and t2 and t2.ST is D but same PO,SKU,LOC should exist in t1 for which ASN is not null.

t1

```
PO | SKU| LOC | ASN |REC | allID
a    b    c      e    NULL  NULL
a    b    c      g     g     12
```

t2

```
PO |SKU |LOC |ASN   |REC |ST
a    b    c   NULL    g   D
```

From above  i should able to delete 2nd row from t1 as on first row same PO,SKU,LOC exist ans ASN is not null.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes but the REC don't match...what exactly do you want???

Comment: Can you show us your SQL code?

Comment: i would have shown the code but the example i presented above is quite simpler version of my own code. Real code is more complex. Thank you for your time. @jambonick.

Comment: @Kostis i have made the change to your concern. Yeah now REC is same. But i got my answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal interpretation of your question turns into two `exists` clauses:

```
delete t1
    where exists (select 1 
                  from t2
                  where t2.PO = t1.PO and t2.SKU = t1.SKU and
                        t2.LOC = t1.LOC and t2.REC = t1.REC and
                        t2.ST = 'D'
                 ) and
           exists (select 1
                   from t1 tt1
                   where tt1.PO = t1.PO and tt1.SKU = t1.SKU and
                         tt1.LOC = t1.LOC and tt1.asn is not null
                  );
```

I'm not 100% sure this is what you really want -- it will delete *all* rows that match.  If this isn't what you want, then you should ask *another* question.  This question already has answers, and it is rude to change the question in a way that invalidates answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like:

```
delete from t1
where (t1.po,t1.sku,t1.loc,t1.rec) in 
  (select t2.po,t2.sku,t2.loc,t2.rec
   from t2
   where t2.st = 'D')
and exists (select * from t1 t1_2
            where t1_2.po  = t1.po
            and   t1_2.sku = t1.sku
            and   t1_2.loc = t1.loc
            and   t1_2.asn is not null);
```